# How to pass an ENV variable from Docker-compose to a Spring Cloud Data Flow Task?

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have Spring Cloud Data Flow that starts from a docker-compose.

For example, in docker-compose I have:

```
dataflow-server:
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:-2.8.1}
    container_name: dataflow-server
    ports:
      - "${DATAFLOW_EXTERNAL_PORT}:9393"
    environment:
      ...
      - MY_ENV=foo
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - skipper-server
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_MOUNT_PATH:-.}:${DOCKER_MOUNT_PATH:-/home/cnb/scdf}
```

But if I register the task with dataflow shell:

```
task create dummy-task --definition 'dummy --MY_ENV_FOR_TASK=$MY_ENV' --description 'dummy task for test'
```

I can't see `MY_ENV_FOR_TASK` resolved as `foo` when I launch the task.

How can I pass an ENV variable, settled in docker-compose `environment` section, to Spring Cloud Data Flow and, successively, to a Task?

Comment: Because the environment variables are there for PID 1 and not for the shell you create later. You should run the `env` command in shell and you will not see `MY_ENV`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the best way of solving this problem is by using the google secret api to set environmet variables.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31433025)